# How do you fill in the parameters for an SQL IN placeholder with HDBC?

Tags: haskell, hdbc

I'm trying to do something like this with Database.HDBC.PostgreSQL:

```
run c "update questions set deleted = now() where question_id in (?)" [toSql ids]
```

where ids is [Int]. But I get the error

```
No instance for (Data.Convertible.Base.Convertible [Int] SqlValue)
```

How do you fill in an IN placeholder with HDBC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can avoid building the query dynamically, but you can still avoid SQL injection and the like.

```
import Control.Applicative ((<$), (<$>))
import Data.List (intersperse)

let query = "update questions set deleted = now() where question_id in ("
            ++ intersperse ',' ('?' <$ ids)
            ++ ")"
 in run c query (toSql <$> ids)
```

Links to documentation for [`intersperse`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base-4.10.1.0/Data-List.html#v:intersperse), [`<$>`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base-4.10.1.0/Control-Applicative.html#v:-60--36--62-), [`<$`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base-4.10.1.0/Control-Applicative.html#v:-60--36-).

Comment: Could you explain a little more how `<$>` and `<$` work? Those links appear to be dead.