# How can I prepare a database query for multiple items in HDBC?

Tags: haskell, hdbc

I have a Sqlite table called `text` that has colums `id` and `text`. I want to get these values out for every row from a list of ids, using HDBC and Haskell. In the sqlite3 command-line program, I can run the query: `select id, text from text where id in (1.0,8.0);` and it works fine. But here's my Haskell code:

```
-- Takes a single string of comma-delimited ids, 
-- e.g. "1.0,2.0,3.0" representing texts to get. 
getFullText conn ids = do
  stmt <- prepare conn "select id, text from text where id in (?)"
  _ <- execute stmt [toSql ids]
  fetchAllRows stmt
```

And if I try `getFullText conn "1.0"` I can get the text for the item with id 1.0. But if I try `getFullText conn "1.0,2.0"` it just returns `[]`.

I think this is because it expands my query to `select text from text where id in ("1.0,8.0")`, instead of `select text from text where id in (1.0,8.0)` or `select text from text where id in ("1.0","8.0")`. What do I need to do to be able to expand `?` into multiple values?

**Edit**: I see that there's a very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16472952/how-do-you-fill-in-the-parameters-for-an-sql-in-placeholder-with-hdbc), but as a haskell beginner, I can't figure out what the magical `<$>` and `<$` operators do. Heres's what I've tried:

```
getFullText conn ids = do
  let query = "select id, text from text where id in (" ++ intersperse ',' ('?' <$ ids) ++ ")"
  stmt <- prepare conn query
  _ <- executeMany stmt ids
  fetchAllRowsAL stmt
```

But when I try applying this function to a `conn` and a list of Sqlvalues, I get `*** Exception: SqlError {seState = "", seNativeError = -1, seErrorMsg = "In HDBC execute, received [SqlByteString \"105.0\"] but expected 20 args."}`. But I think what I'm passing is of length 20, so that should be fine? I think the problem is I don't really understand what `<$` is doing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you fill in the parameters for an SQL IN placeholder with HDBC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16472952/how-do-you-fill-in-the-parameters-for-an-sql-in-placeholder-with-hdbc)

Comment: What is the type of `ids`, and which value you are supplying for it in your test run? (Also, going by [its description in the docs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/HDBC-2.4.0.2/docs/Database-HDBC-Statement.html#v:executeMany) I don't think you need `executeMany` here. Clarifying what your `ids` is should also shed some light on that.)